# Difference of parenthesis of regular expression in Python and egrep

Tags: python, regex, bash

I try to use the same regular expression pattern in Python and Bash, but it is not working in the same way, when the pattern has a parenthesis in it. 
For exemple, I try to look at every "the" in an article.
Here is the pattern

```
"(^|[^a-zA-Z])[Tt]he($|[^a-zA-Z])"
```

In Bash, I write

```
egrep --color "(^|[^a-zA-Z])[Tt]he($|[^a-zA-Z])" Untitled.txt
```

But in Python, if I do this:

```
pattern=re.compile(r"(^|[^a-zA-Z])[Tt]he($|[^a-zA-Z])")
re.findall(pattern, text)
```

I will have the result of what it matches only inside the parenthesis, while I want the "the".

If I want to have the same effet like Bash, I have to repeat:

```
pattern=re.compile(r"^[Tt]he|[^a-zA-Z][Tt]he|[Tt]he$|[Tt]he[^a-zA-Z]")
```

So, my question is, is there any difference about parenthesis in Python and in Bash ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with bash. It's about python vs. egrep.

Comment: Why so complicated? Wouldn't `grep '\<[Tt]he\>'` just work?

Comment: Arguably, the parentheses define capture groups in `grep` and Python. The difference is that `egrep` ignores the capture groups (unless options like `-o` or `--color` are used), while `findall` returns *only* the contents of the capture groups.

Comment: @melpomene I think `\b` would be better, since OP wanted to exclude only letters, not other symbols..

Comment: @joanis What do you think is the difference between `\<` `\>` and `\b`?

Comment: @Pansa, maybe you want to use grouping parentheses around the part you want to keep, with and non-saving ones outside: `(?:...)(...)(?:...)` will save the results of the middle set of parens, but not the two sets with `(?:...)`. So this would mean `(?:^|[^a-zA-Z])([Tt]he)(?:$|[^a-zA-Z])`. Or, much simpler, as melpomene said `\<([Tt]he)\>'`.

Comment: @melpomene in my tests, I thought `grep '\bthe\b'` matched "the.", while `grep '\<the\>'` did not, but I just tested again and I must have misread the output, because they both match. My apologies.

Comment: The capturing groups themselves work the same, just the Python [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) behaves in its own way: *If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.*